# Using javascript, how can I make a full page tab that blurs the background (see pictures)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, figma

I'm developing a portfolio website using tailwinds and javascript. For one portion of the webpage I want a tab to fill the screen with information when the button is clicked. I have the html and css part set up but I don't know how to go about it with javascript. I've used tabs in other areas but those automatically show up upon entering the website. I don't want that to happen for a full page tab. Here is the code I have so far:

```css
/*More tabs*/
.fullscreen {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fullscreen button {
    background-color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Tailwind-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--Work Experience-->
            <div class="bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-lg p-10">
              <h1 id="experience" class="text-3xl font-bold">Work Experience</h1>
              <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-6 pt-10">
                <!--Job tabs (Fullscreen)-->
                <!--Allstate-->
                <div class="fullScreen bg-blue-600">
                  <button class="tabHeader" onclick="workSec(event, 'allstate')">
                    <div class="hover:text-green-300">
                      <div>
                        <img class="rounded-full mx-auto" src="images/Allstate.svg" alt="Allstate Logo" width="150">
                      </div>
                      <p class="pt-2 text-lg">Allstate</p>
                    </div>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <!--Apple-->
                <div class="fullScreen bg-blue-600">
                  <button class="tabHeader" onclick="workSec(event, 'apple')">
                    <div class="hover:text-green-300">
                      <div>
                        <img class="rounded-full mx-auto" src="images/Apple.svg" alt="Apple Logo" width="150">
                      </div>
                      <p class="pt-2 text-lg">Apple</p>
                    </div>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <!--Postogon-->
                <div class="fullScreen bg-blue-600">
                  <button class="tabHeader" onclick="workSec(event, 'postogon')">
                    <div class="hover:text-green-300">
                      <div class="w-40 h-40 rounded-full bg-white mx-auto">
                        <svg aria-label="Home" class="relative top-5 mx-auto" id="logo" width="125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 601 572">
                        <path d="M549.528 354.832C587.161 317.204 549.528 231.128 549.528 163.867C549.528 96.6061 525.301 139.644 473.555 87.9045C421.81 36.1652 428.395 77.7918 374.533 23.936C320.67 -29.9199 277.627 23.936 199.773 23.936C121.684 23.936 59.824 163.867 59.824 163.867C-93.5319 163.867 104.278 326.611 38.4201 392.461C-27.4383 458.311 108.277 462.309 183.544 537.566C258.81 612.823 342.309 537.566 438.98 537.566C535.886 537.566 417.576 427.267 549.293 427.267C681.48 427.502 511.894 392.461 549.528 354.832ZM426.043 357.184C359.715 357.184 419.222 412.686 370.534 412.686C321.846 412.686 279.744 450.55 241.875 412.686C204.007 374.822 135.561 372.706 168.725 339.546C201.89 306.385 102.397 224.308 179.545 224.308C179.545 224.308 210.593 153.755 250.108 153.755C289.387 153.755 311.026 126.709 338.075 153.755C365.124 180.8 361.831 159.869 387.94 185.974C414.048 212.079 426.278 190.442 426.278 224.308C426.278 258.174 445.33 301.447 426.278 320.496C406.991 339.546 492.372 357.184 426.043 357.184Z"></path>
                        </svg></div>
                      <p class="pt-2 text-lg">Postogon</p>
                    </div>
                  </button>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

[image: Before clicking the apple logo]
[image: After clicking the apple logo]

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand correctly what you are trying to do. You want to show an element when a button is clicked? If so, maybe add a class that hides your element and toggle that class when the button is clicked (you should look at the `classList` property of elements)

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean when you say "full page tab" — in your sample images I assume you're clicking on the Apple logo in the first image to get the popup shown in the second image... the second image doesn't take up the "full page", so do you mean that what pops up is its own separate (full) html page? If that's the case you could put it in an `<iframe src="...">` where you set the `src` based on what's been clicked, and as moronator said you keep it hidden and toggle a class so it shows.

Comment: So the full page includes the blur, I was using the blue background to show it "floating" with margins. I can try the getElementById approach and see what happens

Comment: You still don't say where this "floating" part comes from. Is it a hidden div? Is it a page/url on your server? (iframe may be appropriate) Is it an ajax/fetch call? What is the _source_ of that text & logo, and what is the _markup_ surrounding it? (where in the body of your sample html above?) Maybe it's all handled by your `onclick="workSec(...)"` but workSec is missing from your question (your snippet doesn't run, throws an error when you click on something)